# Display adaptive card in facebook message, bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger, adaptive-cards

I have created an adaptive card with C# AdaptiveCard SDK. But, once I deployed to Facebook Messenger, it won't show the adaptive card. 
The key part of code is like this: (including initialize IMessageActivity and set up its properties

```
 var botActivity = (Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity)context.Activity;
 IMessageActivity reply = botActivity.CreateReply();
 reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
 reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

AdaptiveCard adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCard()
{
    Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>
    {                    
        new AdaptiveColumnSet
        {
            Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>
            {                           
                new AdaptiveColumn
                {
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                    {
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                        {
                            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
                            Text = "&#42;",
                            Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Warning
                        }
                    }
                },
                new AdaptiveColumn
                {
                    Size = "1px",
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                    {
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock
                        {
                            Text = "indicates mandatory fields",
                            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium,
                            Wrap = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
        {
            Text = " ",
            Spacing = AdaptiveSpacing.Medium,
        }
    },
    Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
    {
        new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
        {
            Title = "Confirm",
            DataJson = "{\"Type\": \"RequestBody\"}"
        }
    }
};

RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedAdaptiveCard = renderer.RenderCard(adaptiveCard);
Attachment plAttachment = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = renderedAdaptiveCard.OriginatingCard
};

reply.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

I also add the adaptive card to IMessageActivity attachment, and use context.PostAsync to post the reply with attachment back to user.

Anyone has any idea why I can't see the adaptive card in Facebook Messenger?

Comment: Can you add more code details the message send process (not only this part of Attachment generation)?

Comment: @NicolasR Yes, sure thing.

Comment: Is it working on any other channels?

Comment: @JasonSowers yes, it's working fine in WebChat channel.

Comment: Which nuget package are you using `RenderedAdaptiveCard` is not resolving for me, I'm trying to reproduce for you. `RenderedAdaptiveCard renderedAdaptiveCard = renderer.RenderCard(adaptiveCard);`  this line has 2 references not resolving

Comment: @JasonSowers Try this one  AdaptiveCards.Rendering.Html;